# I don't have a clue on how to debug an application in Visual C++ 2008 Express

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

Beginner question: I want to debug some code that compiles. I pressed debug, it asked for an exe file. I browsed and selected the Visual C++ exe. It doesn't work and I don't know how to change it.

1. How to change this EXE file?
2. To what should I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are debugging a DLL. To debug a DLL, make a Win32 console program EXE and then call a function that is exposed by the DLL. Or, you could create Win32 console program (EXE) and put your code into it; then you can debug the EXE directly.